# " ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (109,109) (2,) (109,109) "

Tags: python, numpy, broadcast, astropy, operands

I am using astropy in jupyter notebooks to process fits files. I am using a third party application called pyKLIP.

Can someone explain the construction of this error message as far as it having THREE SETS of parentheses (verbatim, sic). I have found no such construction of this error message which has three sets of parentheses, and that makes it harder to decipher what it needs.

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (109,109) (2,) (109,109)`

The 109,109 can only be the resolution of a fits image, held inside a numpy array of 91 individual frames of 109 rows by 109 columns.

The 2 I cannot yet figure because I cannot get print statements to print inside the third party functions. The only 2 that I know of is an array of 91 sets of an x center and y center.

The spec going into the third party application calls for:

> input = Array of shape (N,y,x) for N images of shape (y,x)
>
> centers = Array of shape (N,2) for N input centers in the format [x_cent, y_cent]

If I print these members as size and shape I get:

```
dataset.input.size      :  1081171
dataset.input.shape     :  (91, 109, 109)
dataset.centers.size    :  182
dataset.centers.shape   :  (91, 2)
```

Any pointers to decipher this broadcast error are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This kind of messages can appear when you apply some operator with `out=` argument like `a = np.random.rand(109, 109); b = np.random.rand(2); np.add(a, b, out=a)`.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? This is a generic error message when arrays do not match. For example, adding two different sized arrays or matrix multiplications with (n x k) and (m x l) where k != m.

Comment: "The 2 I cannot yet figure because I cannot get print statements to print inside the third party functions" if you want to try to debug things yourself, do a search on how to use pdb. It's an invaluable skill.

Answer (score 0):

When searching for help on errors like this focus on the first part of the message, the `broadcast together`.  The `THREE SETS of parentheses` is specific to your case.  Knowing `broadcasting rules` it's obvious that these 3 arrays won't work together.  Your task is to identify which ones.

The fact that you found:

```
dataset.input.shape     :  (91, 109, 109)
dataset.centers.shape   :  (91, 2)
```

suggests that your code (or what's being called) is doing some sort of 'batch' iteration on the first dimension of these arrays, doing something with

```
dataset.input[i]
dataset.centers[i]
```

But without the full traceback we can't say more.  Even with a traceback it can be hard to trace the immediate error back to its source in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to credit the individual whose recommendation let to the solution.

Iguananaut said get a debugger. I researched debuggers, decided Python Visual Debugger was the ticket, then discovered it required Anaconda. Installed Anaconda, then pyklip for Anaconda, then made my own print statements inside Anaconda's pyklip modules, and for whatever reason, Anaconda's pyklip modules were able to execute my print statements.

So, I got to see that the system *desired to add TWO separate ONE-instance two-element tuples, but was being *fed a ONE-instance two-element tuple + a NNN-instance array of two-element tuples. This was precisely the line number where the failure message said it was.

I will have to check more, but I think the spec might have been vague enough so as to allow wrong conclusions. I *think that "centers = Array of shape (N,2) for N input centers in the format [x_cent, y_cent]" should say the equivalent of "shape (1,2)". (IIRC tuples have no shape members..)

Can anyone speak to how or why Anaconda's installation of a third party library,  pyklip, allows print statements inside pyklip code to successfully execute, whereas the github repo of pyklip did *Not allow print statements inside pyklip code to successfully execute?

The material answer to the opening question is that the 109 row by 109 column needs to have each cell value shifted up or down by a very small amount to effect a re-centering of the image. It could not get to that point because the dx and dy, differences between the TWO separate ONE-instance two-element tuples, could not be calculated correctly.